# "On a similar note" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've been hearing this phrase from time to time and the (free) online dictionaries that I have access to and that show up on my IP address don't have any entry for it. It's meaning may be obvious but like most phrases in English, I doubt it's that simple.

Example:

> **On a similar note**, be sure to read Mary Pilon's post on one veteran who is encouraging today's soldiers to do the same

I think here it means "similarly" and something along the lines of this was said earlier.

Another example:

> 4. Attendance at sporting events might soon be allowed.
> 5. **On a similar note**, movie theatres might soon be reopening.
>
> [BC Local News](https://www.bclocalnews.com/opinion/the-editors-desk-getting-back-to-normal/)

It probably means "similarly" here too, but I need a second opinion.

So what does this phrase originally mean? Does it only mean "similarly" or depending on the context, its meaning can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the definition of *note* (related to the idea of a musical note) -

> a particular quality or tone that reflects or expresses a mood or attitude (Oxford Dictionaries)

You are correct in thinking that it means *on a similar theme* or *speaking from a similar point of view.*

Answer (score 0):

***Similarly*** is among the synonyms of *on a similar note* provided by [Power Thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/on_a_similar_note/synonyms).

I had thought of *along the same lines* or *[from the same perspective](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/from_the_same_perspective/synonyms)*.

It can also mean simply ***in addition***.

The particular ***note*** in this idiom may also refer to a written note, it seems:

> It is unclear exactly how this idiom originated. Some sources
> speculate that it comes from a musical note. This seems to make sense.
> The notes of music can sound happy or sad, and they could
> metaphorically represent upbeat or upsetting conversations.
> Alternatively, it could relate to written notes or comments. A meeting
> might cover different bullet points or notes. If one wanted to
> transition from one of these notes to another, it would make sense to
> use this expression.

([WritingExplained](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/on-that-note))

Comment: If a story or sequence of events ended with an unhappy happening, we can say it ended on a 'sad note'.